# Sergeant Sequence takes the case

Tags: knowledge, pattern, geography, sequence

It was 2am and Sergeant Sequence had been called in to Headquarters urgently.  The second he stepped through the door a file was pressed into his hands by the Chief Investigator, who began to talk extremely fast while steering him towards a side-corridor.

“Patrick Terne is at it again.  Triple poisoning this time – arsenic – huge quantities of it; he wasn’t taking any chances.  Fled London, hopped about all over the world, but the trail’s gone cold.  We traced him through eleven different countries but he’s gone totally off grid.  Of course, we suspect there is some kind of pattern to his movements – there always is – but we can’t spot it…  We need your eye on this case – you know him well; if anyone can get into Terne’s mind, you can…”

It was true – Sergeant Sequence had come up against Terne on several occasions before, and each time he had been able to determine the method to his madness.  Staring down at the list in his hands, Sequence pondered the countries written there…

> 1. Vietnam
> 2. Finland
> 3. Portugal
> 4. Germany
> 5. Colombia
> 6. Moldova
> 7. Tonga
> 8. Canada
> 9. Tuvalu
> 10. India
> 11. Kenya
>
> *But then where…?!*

After just two minutes of thought, something clicked.  “He’s still in Kenya,” he said.  “Send your best team out there.”

“How can you be so sure?” the Chief Investigator asked, an eyebrow raised.

“I know how this guy's mind works,” Sequence replied.  “And trust me – if he’s done what I think he has it would have been impossible to make a twelfth move.”

**TASK: Identify the pattern behind the sequence “Vietnam, Finland, Portugal, Germany, Colombia, Moldova, Tonga, Canada, Tuvalu, India, Kenya” and explain why it ends there.**

**Hint:**

> The sequence relies on TWO pieces of knowledge in combination.

Comment: V unir gnxra nyy gur pbhagevrf naq ercynprq gurz jvgu gurve fhz (nppbeqvat gb rnpu pbhagel'f nycunorgf' vaqvprf naq nsgre nqqvat H+00<fhz sbe rnpu pbhagel> guvf vf jung V tbg: 
nUE0pUZ6Yl9jLKA0MJWcov5wo20iImN1IJIlHGH=

Nz V ba gur evtug genpx?

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Note there's no [tag:mathematics] tag and no [tag:cipher] tag - don't go down that path! :)

Comment: I spent far too long trying to find significance in the name before I got it :)

Comment: Stiv, does it have anything to do with the course?like a geometric design on the map drawing the line of the consecutive destinations.

Comment: @Craftsman No extensive drawing exercises required - just brainpower :)

Comment: I've been trying do do something with the capital cities as I can't see anything else that they all have in common apart from all having one. Not come up with anything yet but maybe it gives someone smarter than me an idea.

Comment: I've noticed that each change goes north, then south, then north, then south, etc., but staying in kenya would require that there is nothing north of kenya. which, obviously, isn't true...

Comment: @Stiv should we be counting united kingdom as the first item in the list?

Comment: @kristinalustig You can ignore the UK as the starting point - it's about the places he goes *to*, i.e. just the 11 on the piece of paper. Good, insightful question.

Comment: @ Stiv Another idea tha came in my mind.Does it have anything to do with history?

Comment: @Craftsman Not directly... I'll add a hint.

Comment: Hey Stiv: I have an idea for a sequel to this puzzle. Do you mind if I post it?

Comment: @JeremyDover Feel free, as long as you don't kill them off! :) (Although if I reuse the characters I am more likely to do a prequel anyway...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First take the capital cities of the countries in order

> Hanoi
>  Helsinki
>  Lisbon
>  Berlin
>  Bogota
>  Chisinau
>  Nuku'alofa
>  Ottawa
>  Funafuti
>  New Delhi
>  Nairobi

Now notice that

> The beginning of each capital city gives the chemical symbols for the first $11$ elements of the periodic table in order.
>  **H**anoi
>  **He**lsinki
>  **Li**sbon
>  **Be**rlin
>  **B**ogota
>  **C**hisinau
>  **N**uku'alofa
>  **O**ttawa
>  **F**unafuti
>  **Ne**w Delhi
>  **Na**irobi

So the next country he would have to visit would have to have

> Its capital city begin with **Mg** which does not exist.

Comment: Weirdly, I *knew* it would be you who ended up solving this! Well done - this is exactly the right logic :) (Note one typo in the bold text of your second block though...)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, yes, thank you, got over excited. Great puzzle!