# What is a Watchful Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This puzzle is based on and inspired by the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by JLee that have grown into Word™, [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2), and [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Watchful Word™.

This is a list of Watchful Words™ and Not Watchful Words™.

| Watchful Word™ | Not Watchful Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| Sinovac | Phizer |
| Paprika | Pepper |
| Mayonnaise | Mustard |
| Smart | Stupid |
| Horsepower | Watts |
| Nocturnal | Diurnal |
| Daughter | Son |
| Junior | Senior |
| Azerbaijan | Georgia |
| Lifeboat | Barge |
| Decrease | Increase |

CSV:

```
Watchful Word™, Not Watchful Word™
Sinovac, Phizer
Paprika, Pepper
Mayonnaise, Mustard
Smart, Stupid
Horsepower, Watts
Nocturnal, Diurnal
Daughter, Son
Junior, Senior
Azerbaijan, Georgia
Lifeboat, Barge
Decrease, Increase
```

**Hint:**

> The seventh is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Watchful Word is

> One which contains a substring corresponding to the first three letters in the name of a month of the year

Examples

> Si**nov**ac
>  P**apr**ika
>  **May**onnaise
>  S**mar**t
>  Hor**sep**ower
>  N**oct**urnal
>  D**aug**hter
>  **Jun**ior
>  Azerbai**jan**
>  Li**feb**oat
>  **Dec**rease

Hint

> No word with **jul** (corresponding to July, the seventh month) is listed

Comment: Haha, you were ready for this question [a long time (9 months) ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/can-i-have-a-p-please-bob#comment304727_107757)! :)

Comment: @Stiv Haha, I had actually forgotten about the fact that you used this feature. But yes, lifeboat was a huge beacon for me, here.

Comment: Do we have a record for fastest solve?Accepting though there is still why they're named "Watchful".